# unable to get Image URL from function

Tags: php, image, function

Am using `php Function` to get image URL from sql 
but am unable to get image url

function code to get image url

```
function getUsers() {//returns an array of users
    global $db;
    $list = array();
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM user_info');
    $users = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (is_array($users) || is_object($users)) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            array_push($list, $user[0]);
        }return $list;
    }
}

$users = getUsers();

function getImageURL($user) {
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT propic FROM user_info WHERE username=:username');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $user));
    $source = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $source;
}
```

and here is code to display image

```
<?php
                $user = $_GET['myUser'];
                if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                    $loggedIn = $_SESSION['username'];
                }

                $s = getImageURL($user);
            foreach($s as $URL){
                echo "<img class=\"full\" src=\"$URL[0] \" alt=\"$user's profile picture ERROR PART\"/>";
            }
                ?>
```

My database connection and user name everything works fine
[image]

Comment: what is the output of $URL[0] ?

Comment: it should be `$URL['propic']`

Comment: its just s value = "s" i have attached image

Comment: @CodeGodie Doesn't works

Comment: try this print_r($URL[0]);exit; check whether link is getting or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting two things:

- [**`fetchAll()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to obtain your array result set

  change this:

  ```
  $source = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```

  to this:

  ```
  $source = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```

---

- the correct way to grab your array elements per iteration

  change this:

  ```
  $URL[0]
  ```

  to this:

  ```
  $URL['propic']
  ```